# How to keep X-Server running via 'ssh -Y' after closing shell?

Tags: ssh, python, scripts

my name is Chris and i have trouble to run a Python-Script on a Server.

I try to run a Python Script, that makes use of the Python module wx, on a Server.
Therefor i open a shell connect to the server via 'ssh -Y' then im running the script with an ' & ' at the end. Everything works fine bunt when i logout the program causes an internal error ( Something with X Display ... i don't remember exact ). It's the same error i get when i connect without ' -Y'. 
So what can i do if i want to logout and keep the X-Server running? or is it something else?

Thank You for Your help!

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

Running the script with an ampersand behind it means that it will be backgrounded in the shell. So, it is still running even though you get a prompt. (Type `jobs` at that prompt and you will see it.)

To not get the error when exiting the ssh session, either foreground the script first by typing `fg` at the prompt, then stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or stop it by typing `kill %1` at the prompt.

Comment: Thank You for helping me. But i want to keep the script running with the graphic support i get from the ' -Y' and that is beeing shout down when logging out.

Comment: @Chris The program is running on the remote computer. Its graphical output flows though the ssh connection back to the local computer, where the X server displays it on your screen. When you terminate the ssh connection, how is the program going to send its graphical output to your screen?